# How to print the default value of an object?

Tags: java, null, default

If t1 gives compile error, t2 prints memory address, t3 prints null, 
then what would you write to get the default value of an object (null) printed.

```
public class Test {

public Test{

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t1;                              
    Test t2= new Test();                  
    Test t3= null;                        
    System.out.println(t1);            //compile error uninitialized
    System.out.println(t2);            //prints memory address
    System.out.println(t3);            //prints null

}
}
```

Comment: Don't understand the question.  You're already doing it.

Comment: that's because i assigned null to t3. Doesn't java has a default? so without assignment it should know it can take null

Comment: No, Java does not have a default for method-local variables. You need to assign a value before using the variable. See my answer below.

Comment: @Square-root Please don't change the question like that while people are answering it, because it invalidates all previous answers. You can add new information below the original question, but completely changing it is very confusing and not nice to the people who previously answered your question

Comment: Objects don't have default values. Their *member variables* have default values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only instance or static variables (declared at class scope) have a default value. Local variable (declared at method scope) do not have default values: you are required to initialize these variables before you use them.

So the compiler is correct when it rejects the printing of `t1` (with a compile error): you haven't assigned a value to this variable at that point in the method, and it's a local variable, so it does *not* have a default value.

Comment: I moved t1 to the class level. it gives non-static variable t1 cannot be referenced from a static context (runtime error)

Comment: @Square-root Make it a `static` variable then (since the `main` method is also `static`)

Answer (score 2):

The variables here are local variables in a method. From Java [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variablesummary.html):

> The compiler will assign a reasonable default value for fields of the
>   above types; **for local variables, a default value is never assigned**.

So you need to initialize them manually.

Answer (score 0):

**only variables have default values**. An object contains said variables or other objects wich also contain variables or other objects etc.